# typoscript bootstrap navigation third level typo3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I've got the following TypoScript code for my TYPO3 page to use the bootstrap navigation.

```
       MENU = HMENU
    MENU.entryLevel = 0
    #NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

    MENU {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1

    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    IFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
    IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
    IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB.before = <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    ACTIFSUB.after =  <b class="caret"></b></a>
    ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown active">|</li>
    ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
  }

       2 = TMENU
  2 {
    expAll = 1

    ACT = 1
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    ACTIFSUB = 1
    ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = |
    ACTIFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
    ACTIFSUB.after = </li>
    ACTIFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.before = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">
    IFSUB.after = </li>
    IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
    IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

    SPC = 1
    SPC.allWrap = <li class="divider"></li><li class="nav-header">|</li>

    wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
  }
```

this works absolute fine if I have a 2 level navigation. How can I print out navigation points of the third level?

They should just be shown under the second level

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*How can I print out navigation points of the third level?*"

Exactly the same as in the second level (and the same in 4-th, 5-th ... 99th) what's more you don't need to write the full definitions in each level as you can *inherit* it from some earlier one and just override what's required. Sample which works well with Bootstrap 3

```
10 = HMENU
10 {
    1 = TMENU
    1.expAll = 1
    1 {
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>

        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="dropdown">|</li>
        IFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"

        ACTIFSUB < .ACT
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active dropdown">|</li>
        ACTIFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
    }

    2 < .1 // level 2
    2 {
        wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    }

    3 < .2 // level 3
    4 < .2 // level 4
    5 < .2 // level 5
    // ...
    99 < .2 // level 99
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work like mine... only print some li from third leved. screenshot added above.

Comment: problem solved. Just have to delete this:  `wrap = <ul class="dropdown-menu">|</ul>` in the third level